# do we really need two "favorite inspiration" wiki questions?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

[What is your favourite photographic inspiration?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2224/what-is-your-favourite-photographic-inspiration)

[Which photographer do you find inspirational?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7520/which-photographer-do-you-find-inspirational)

These seem to be very very similar, to the point there are a few answers that are duplicated. Merge and close one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that they are duplicates, but I think

> which *photographer* do you find inspirational

Is a far more useful form than

> Share a *photo* you find inspirational

Since, looking at a photographer allows you to study them as a professional, their techniques, their approach, etc. It's a better, more generally useful way to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you there, they are both very similar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm voting to close, a mod could merge the two.

Answer (score 0):

I read the first one [What is your favourite photographic inspiration?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2224/what-is-your-favourite-photographic-inspiration) is in other words asking *"what inspires you in photography time and time again?"*

My answer would have been: "Sunrise is the thing that again and again inspires me." and given one example shot of my own photos of a sunrise.

I read the other one impossible for me to answer, because there is no such photographer that inspires me. How could there be, I don't know any photographer well enough. I hardly recognise some names when I see them mentioned on the PhotoSE site. So I could not have answered that question in any way.

So, to my eyes, they were far different questions, asking for totally different answers. But I guess I read the questions somehow wrong, because here it looks like everybody is thinking them as duplicates.

What more, they are **both** closed. A duplicate pointing to a closed question. End of story.

Comment: must be the word "photographic" that I'm misreading.